# Calculating TotalHeap Size in G1GC

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, cut

How do i Read G1 Heap used variable using a shell script in the below example. i tried using awk with no luck

jmap -heap

```
Heap Usage:
G1 Heap:
regions  = 2048
capacity = 8589934592 (8192.0MB)
used     = 4976717264 (4746.167434692383MB)
free     = 3613217328 (3445.832565307617MB)
57.93661419302225% used

G1 Young Generation:
Eden Space:
regions  = 234
capacity = 3854565376 (3676.0MB)
used     = 981467136 (936.0MB)
free     = 2873098240 (2740.0MB)
25.462459194776933% used
Survivor Space:
regions  = 14
capacity = 58720256 (56.0MB)
 used     = 58720256 (56.0MB)
free     = 0 (0.0MB)
100.0% used

G1 Old Generation:
regions  = 941
capacity = 4676648960 (4460.0MB)
used     = 3936529872 (3754.167434692383MB)
free     = 740119088 (705.8325653076172MB)
84.17415772852877% used
```

Comment: Could you please do check my solution once and do lemme know if this helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. I am using `exit` so when first match found for `Heap Usage` and then first match of string `used` is found it will print requested value and exit immediately from program, so this will be faster also.

```
awk '/Heap Usage:/{found=1;next} found && /used/{print $3;exit}'  Input_file
```